# fineuploader s3 and resume options

Tags: fine-uploader

i'm using fineuploader s3 and i've just discovered a unexpected ( from my pov ) behaviour.
I give to our customers the possibility to upload files for their works.
Every work has a code for example 12345_1298681 and 12345_84792782.
let's assume that customer started to upload files for both orders ( starting the upload sets the work as interrupted so at next uploader init them are set as _isResumable = true)
User uploads file a.mov to work 12345_1298681 ( s3key is 12345_1298681/a.mov ) and b.mov to 12345_84792782 ( s3Key is 12345_84792782/b.mov)
If for some reason user tries to upload a.mov to work 12345_84792782 fineuploader recognizes the file as resumables and in the console i can see

```
Identified file with ID 0 and name of a.mov as resumable.
Server requested UUID change from '60aecf65-67ca-4811-aa3c-6425620cc3f1' to 'a2bfc111-0c82-4e48-8512-a08c3e24cbd8'
```

But a.mov is resumable if added to work 12345_1298681 not if added to work 12345_84792782.
i've seen in the doc that if i return false to the onResume callback the file is restarted from the beginning, but the problem whit this approach is that resume data is deleted for the file and not for the s3Key and in this way i'll lose the ability to resume upload in 12345_1298681?

To be clearer ( hopefully ) 
i have
order 12345_123456 => s3 key => 12345_123456/a.mov
order 12345_987654 => s3 key => 12345_987654/a.mov
if i start to upload file for order 12345_123456 than i stop it, if i want start the upload for order 12345_987654 using the same file in my filesystem, fineuploader recognizes that the file is the same ( that's correct but it differs in the final key ) and uploads it to 12345_123456/a.mov instead of 12345_987654/a.mov
and this can lead to a problem: 
 i think i'm uploading file for one order instead i'm not.
Digging in the source of fineuploader i can see that the cookie id is generated by function
_getLocalStorageId from qq.XhrUploadHandler
instead of
_getLocalStorageId from qq.s3.XhrUploadHandler but in none of those methods there's something that consider key to differentiate file from another

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Well, i admit that it may not be clear. simply i want to prevent that if i add the same file to order a and than add it to order b the file is recognized as resumable and change the s3key by itself